# Elastic search spring boot ZonedDateTime converter not mapping correctly

Tags: spring, mongodb, elasticsearch

I know a similar question has been asked before [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62129636/4230855) but I think my problem is a bit different. I have an job board app that uses `MongoDB`as it's `primary database`, when data enters mongo is it synced to my `Elasticsearch cluster automatically`, all my date objects are `ZonedDateTime` due to the fact that even `MongoDB` does not have a converter for ZonedDateTime, I use this as my converter, I stored the datefield as an object with a `dateTime`, `zoneId` and `offset`, below is how it looks in the database

[image]

And the code responsible for that conversion is as follows:
My Writing converter

```
@WritingConverter
public class ZonedDateTimeToMongoDocumentConverter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, Document> {
    static final String DATE_TIME = "dateTime";
    static final String ZONE = "zone";

    @Override
    public Document convert(@Nullable ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        if (zonedDateTime == null) return null;

        Document document = new Document();
        document.put(DATE_TIME, zonedDateTime.toInstant().getEpochSecond() * 1_000);
        document.put(ZONE, zonedDateTime.getZone().getId());
        document.put("offset", zonedDateTime.getOffset().toString());
        return document;
    }
}
```

And my reading converter

```
    @ReadingConverter
public class MongoDocumentToZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Document, ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(@Nullable Document document) {
        if (document == null) return null;


        Date dateTime = document.getDate(DATE_TIME);
        String zoneId = document.getString(ZONE);
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(zoneId);

        return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(dateTime.toInstant(), zone);
    }
}
```

And my Codec

```
public class ZonedDateTimeCodec implements Codec<ZonedDateTime> {

public static final String DATE_TIME = "dateTime";
public static final String ZONE = "zone";

@Override
public void encode(final BsonWriter writer, final ZonedDateTime value, final EncoderContext encoderContext) {
    writer.writeStartDocument();
    writer.writeDateTime(DATE_TIME, value.toInstant().getEpochSecond() * 1_000);
    writer.writeString(ZONE, value.getZone().getId());
    writer.writeEndDocument();
}

@Override
public ZonedDateTime decode(final BsonReader reader, final DecoderContext decoderContext) {
    reader.readStartDocument();
    long epochSecond = reader.readDateTime(DATE_TIME);
    String zoneId = reader.readString(ZONE);
    reader.readEndDocument();

    return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond / 1_000), ZoneId.of(zoneId));
}

@Override
public Class<ZonedDateTime> getEncoderClass() {
    return ZonedDateTime.class;
}
```

}

This code works great issue though is when the data enters `Elasticsearch`, because of the nature of my date fields I had to opt for the datefields to be stored as objects as well and the mapping

```
{
    "myDateField": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "dateTime": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "zone": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "offSet": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> PS: Am new to Elasticsearch, this is in fact my first attempt at it.

Then I create my spring `ZonedDateTime elastic converters` as follows

Writing converter

```
@ReadingConverter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StringToZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, ZonedDateTime> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(String source) {
        ZoneDateTime zoneDateTime = objectMapper.readValue(source, ZoneDateTime.class);
        return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(zoneDateTime.getDateTime().toInstant(), ZoneId.of(zoneDateTime.getZone()));
    }
}
```

Reading converter

```
@WritingConverter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ZonedDateTimeToStringConverter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, String> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public String convert(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ZoneDateTime.builder()
                .dateTime(Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant()))
                .zone(zonedDateTime.getZone().getId())
                .offSet(zonedDateTime.getOffset().toString())
                .build());
    }
}
```

And my `ZoneDateTime` class looks like

```
    @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class ZoneDateTime {

    private final Date dateTime;
    private final String offSet;
    private final String zone;


}
```

From my understanding this should work, but spring gives me this error

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value '2020-08-08T14:32:22.094Z'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values
at [Source: (String)"2020-08-08T14:32:22.094Z"; line: 1, column: 6]
```

And really not sure why Elasticsearch only sends the `dateTime` field from the dateField object leaving the `zone` and `offset`, `elasticsearch` ignores the fact that my datefield is an object. How can I fix this ?

Comment: My guess is you have some of the timestamps stored in the database as strings.

Comment: @D.SM I would have said the same until I looked up the exact field causing the error, it look ok to me `{
            "dateTime" : "2020-08-08T14:32:22.094Z",
            "offset" : "+02:00",
            "zone" : "Africa/Johannesburg"
          }`

Comment: That tells you the datetime value is a string.